Filtered Rows Count in DevExpress XtraGrid Incorrect
Filtered Rows Count in DevExpress XtraGrid Incorrect when row is selected.
My filtered grid record displays 1 row in the grid and the following code return a count of 1. But, when I select it, the same following code returns a count of 2.
Dim nCount = MyXGrid.RowCount

I've also tried
Dim nCount = MyXGrid.GetSelectedRowCount

Google and several other articles from DevExpress

This question was asked yesterday. As far as I remember, this is the same question word for word. What happened to that one?

You can use the following code to get selected rows count
Dim nCount = MyXGrid.GetSelectedRows().Length


This code also returns 2

Can you post your code in detail. above command works fine as I have tested.

I want to get a count of selected rows from a list of filtered records.
For example: My grid displays 25 rows, I filter records and it displays 1 row. When I select this row (1 record selected out of 1). When I get a count of selected records using the following code, it return a count of 2 instead of 1(I've selected ONLY 1 row).
Dim nCount = MyXGrid.GetSelectedRowCount
Messagebox.Show(nCount) 'It displays 2
Dim nCount = MyXGrid.GetSelectedRowCount
Messagebox.Show(nCount)   'It displays 2   *** ONLY 1 RECORD WAS SELECTED.  IF I SELECT 2 RECORDS THEN IT REURNS 3

I have tested vb.net code for your reference.  I am using Devexpress 24.1

Dim sel = gvVDR.GetSelectedRows()
MsgBox("Selected Row(s) Count: " + sel.Length.ToString())

I cannot find GetSelectedRowCount function in Devexpress winforms
